Operation must use an updatable query. System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
I am working on exporting data to a DBF file using OLEDB and have encountered an issue. When I execute an SQL query to insert or update data, I sometimes get the following error:

Operation must use an updateable query.

Here is an example of my SQL query:
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("insert into [{0}] ([DOGOVOR],[NOMPOINT],[FIO],[ADRESS],[MARK],[DIGIT],[NUMBER],[DATE],[IND1],[IND2],[IND3],[CONST_CODE])" + "values (@DOGOVOR,@NOMPOINT,@FIO,@ADRESS,@MARK,@DIGIT,@NUMBER,@DATE,@IND1,@IND2,@IND3,@CONST_CODE)", fileName);                    
    
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOGOVOR", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = numberUsk ?? "N/A";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NOMPOINT", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = nomPointUsk ?? "N/A";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FIO", OleDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = fio;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ADRESS", OleDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = prevRow.Address ?? "N/A";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MARK", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = prevRow.Mark ?? "N/A";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DIGIT", OleDbType.Integer).Value = prevRow.DigitsNumber;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMBER", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = prevRow.IsDeviceNumberNull() ? "N/A" : prevRow.DeviceNumber;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@DATE", lastDate.ToOADate()));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IND1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ind1;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IND2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ind2;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IND3", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ind3;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CONST_CODE", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 0;
                        int attempt = 0;
                        bool success = false;
                        
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

The issue occurs inconsistently: sometimes the query works correctly, and other times it throws the above error.
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathToDbf + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password="; OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString); conn.Open();
    
           OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"CREATE TABLE [{0}] ([DOGOVOR] varchar(100)," +
                                                                 "[NOMPOINT] varchar(20)," +
                                                                 "[FIO] varchar(250)," +
                                                                 "[ADRESS] varchar(250)," +
                                                                 "[MARK] varchar(100)," +
                                                                 "[DIGIT] int," +
                                                                 "[NUMBER] varchar(100)," +
                                                                 "[DATE] date," +
                                                                 "[IND1] int," +
                                                                 "[IND2] int," +
                                                                 "[IND3] int," +
                                                                 "[CONST_CODE] int)", fileName);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


I have checked the following:
The DBF file is in a directory with write permissions.
The file is not open in another process or program.
The fields in the query match the fields in the DBF file structure.
